# submit characters with query ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to sumbit Georgian characters with ajax. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
        nameGeo: $('#sauceNameGeo').val(),
        nameEng: $('#sauceNameEng').val(),
        nameRus: $('#sauceNameRus').val(),
        descriptionGeo: $('#sauceDescGeo').val(),
        descriptionEng: $('#sauceDescEng').val(),
        descriptionRus: $('#sauceDescRus').val()
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    $('#sauceNameGeo').val('');
    $('#sauceNameEng').val('');
    $('#sauceNameRus').val('');
    $('#sauceDescGeo').val('');
    $('#sauceDescEng').val('');
    $('#sauceDescRus').val('');
    $('.table-hotdog-sauces > tbody:last').append(response);
    alertify.success("Data has been saved");
});
```

However on the server side I am receiving wrong characters. Something like question marks. When submiting with regular form everything works fine but I need to submit it with ajax.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use `data:$('formID').serialize()` .

Comment: If you cant accomplish the goal with ajax, you could always submit the form to a hidden iframe.

Comment: no I am still getting this on the server: HotDogSauce [id=null, nameGeo=áá¡á¤áá¡áá¯á. form serialize didn't help

Answer (score 2):

did you try to set right charset?

```
contentType:  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=yours'
```

Comment: I would say directly `charset=utf-8` since we have Latin, Cyrillic and Georgian. :)